# Preimages of discs by an entire function and connectedness

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a surjective entire function of the complex plane. Does there exist a real number $r_0>0$ such that the set $f^{-1}(D(0,r))$ is connected for any $r\geq r_0$?

Answer (score 0):

Not always, take as an example the function $f(z) = z \sin \pi z$. Then $f(k) = 0$ for all integers $k$, so $A_r = f^{-1}(D(0,r))$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $r>0$. However, on the lines $\Re z = k+1/2$ we have that $|f(z)| \ge k+1/2$, which implies that for $k \ge r$ these lines are not contained in $A_r$, which shows that $A_r$ always has infinitely many connected components, for every $r>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!